# Interface builder constraints for enlarging buttons with the screen size

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints

really new to the interface builder. I have 5 buttons evenly spaced. Setup in the iPhone5 screen. I want the spacing between the buttons and the boundaries to remain the same but the buttons to grow in size with the screen (keeping the same aspect ratio).

[image]

How would I setup the constraints for this ? Do I need to put invisible spacers between the buttons or something to do this?

Comment: there always will be 7 buttons?

Answer (score 3):

Do like this:

1. Put all buttons inside `UIView`
2. Set constraint to `UIView` as **leading**, **top** ,**Trailing**, **height** and **width**.
3. Set constraints to all the buttons inside UIView as **top**,**leading**,**width** and **height**.
4. Then select first button and `UIView` together, and **make them equal widths** and set the multiplier of this constraint as per your number of buttons need, at this point set priority of `UIView's` width constraint to 900 (this is important). Same with button's width constraint.
5. Now select all buttons and **set them as equal width** and set the multiplier of this constraint as per your button's width.
6. **Delete** width constraint of all the buttons except first one.

Comment: How do you select the first button and UIView together? Command click them in the left pane? Having trouble finding the multiplier for it too.

Answer (score 2):

**View heirarchy:**

[image]

**Final Output:**

[image]

**Solutions:**

I have started implementing constraints from the button in the center i.e. Button4

**1) Constraints on Holder View**

HolderView.centerY = superview.centery

HolderView trailing/leading constraints to superview

**2) Constraints on Button4**

Button4.width = Button4.height

Button4.width = HolderView.superview.width * (1/7) - 10
   *(yes it is not a typo Button4.width is relative to screen width not its holder view's width)*

Button4.trailing to Spacer, Button4.leading to Spacer

Button4 bottom/top constraints to superview

Make all other buttons equal to Button4 (button in the center)

**3)** If you need to have the same arrangement for any number of button you just have to play with width constraint of the button in the center

**Sample Project :**

Link to [Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0t6tyznq359w23m/AABZ58kNa4Nt9-1-RqsJuBjza?dl=0)

**Note: *This solutions will work on only odd number of buttons***

Comment: How do I enter Button4.width = HolderView.superview.width * (1/7) - 10? Do I need to click on the constraint to edit it?

Comment: yes in multiplier you will mention 1:7 and in constant -10, it can be seen in test project as well. General constraint equation looks like A.attribute = B.Attribute * multiplier + constant

Comment: Ah, I see. How do you make a width constraint relative to HolderView.superview.width though? I first click on the middle button, then add constraint for width. I then click on the width constraint but there isn't a multiplier option.

Comment: you will not add constraint for width, width constraints are fixed constraints they won't scale as per screen size, you will use aspect ratio constraint

Comment: You said make all the buttons equal to button 4. Are you physically copying and pasting the buttons or just following the instructions again for each button?

Comment: making other buttons equal to button4 means that on the other buttons constraints will be equal width and equal height to button4